# word 2016 omml to mml equations

Tags: microsoft-word, mathtype

I have several documents in word 2016 with a few hundred equations written in the native word equation format (i think it is omml). I want to convert every equation to mathml. what is the quickest way?
I have already installed mathtype but it says omml2mml.xsl missing. Even after locating the file and putting it where the mathtype website said, it is showing same error. How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

There exists an open source framework called `transpect`.
It's purpose is conversion of complete documents from and to individual formats. (`docx`, TeX, html...)
Among others, `docx` files are supported as input:

https://github.com/transpect/

If you have git or svn installed, you can simply follow this guide for a basic setup:

http://transpect.github.io/getting-started.html

The guide describes converting the whole `docx` document into `hub.xml` (basically docbook+css).
Both, `MathType` and `OMML` equations are translated to `MathML` during conversion.
You can simply extract the `mml:math` elements from the `hub.xml`, using any tool you like.

There exist more transpect modules, to convert the `hub.xml` to your desired format completely.
That requires more time for setup, so it depends on what you intend to do with the results.

### Background

The old Word Equation Editor was built upon `MathType`.
The new Word Equation Editor is based on `OMML`.

A `MathType`-Equation is displayed as an image in Word.
If you have `MathType` installed, a separate window opens if you click to edit the equation.
Else, you cannot edit it.
New equations (`OMML`) can be edited directly inside the Word software.

`OMML` and `MathML` are both XML-formats.
`omml2mml.xsl` is a file provided by Microsoft to go from `OMML` to `MathML`.
`transpect` uses a modified variant of it, because the original file has several flaws.
(There also exists `mml2omml.xsl`, to go from `MathML` to `OMML`)

`MathType` uses a non-XML-structure for its equations.
`MathType` can import `MathML` equations, but not `OMML`.
`MathType` therefore requires the `omml2mml.xsl` file to generate `MathML` first.

On a side note, `MathType` does not always preserve character styles (bold/italic) when exporting to MathML/TeX.

To support all equation-types in Word, and to improve the performance of conversion, `transpect` is able to translate `MathType` to `MathML`.

For your info: *I am a contributor to the transpect project*.